# Using AdminDirectory API to get a member email alias

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script which retrieves a new member registration from a form and add his email to a google group. I am using the AdminDirectory.Members.insert(NewMember, groupEmail) method. before calling the method I wish to check if the member  email already exists in the group. for that I do a DO loop on:
page = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail,{
      domain: groupDomainName,
      orderBy: 'Email',
      maxResults: 200,
      pageToken: pageToken
      });
the problem with this method is that it does not retrieve data about email aliases, and so, after not finding a match on the new member email and trying to add his email to the group, I get an error that the member already exists. manual check using Google Groups Admin Console shows that the member was once registered with a different email and somehow, google recognizes the new email but not showing it on the members list, does not come up in members' search and also not shows up using AdminDirectory.Members.list.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? Also check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Yes. I have a member who apparently uses two email addresses, one of them gmail. when I

Comment: Yes. I have a member who uses two email addresses, one of them gmail. upon membership renewal, the member chooses to renew membership with a different email. I scan the list and if I dont find the email in the list, I add the member with his "new" address, I get an error "member already exists". after deep manual checking it appears that the member was once registered with his non gmail address, and somehow google group recognizes it as belongs to the same person. I now learned that it has to do something with google "big data"...Also, I manage members only by email address and not by names...